# Where is this passage by Nabokov on the power of language located?

Tags: quote-source, vladimir-nabokov

I’m losing my mind, because I’ve lost a quotation that I had a few weeks ago and now can’t relocate it for the life of me. It was from either Brian Boyd’s two-volume biography of Nabokov or Boyd's book *Stalking Nabokov*, and it is a page in which he states something to the effect of “We may suspect that language can't accurately capture reality" and then he quotes a short vivid passage by Nabokov that implicitly invokes then refutes this idea. It's likely a passage from one of his novels.